Can you attempt a risky task without risking your mind or body?
When playing Rooted in Trophy games, you roll dice "when you attempt a risky task":

When you attempt a risky task, say what you hope will happen and ask the GM and the other players what could possibly go wrong. Then gather 6-sided dice.

However, the rules also say that there's an option "if you are risking your mind or body":

Add a dark die if you are risking your mind or body to attempt the task.

Does this assume that you can  attempt a risky task without risking your mind or body? How exactly is this possible? Do you risk other things (e.g. equipment), or there's no imminent risk, but the situation becomes worse? or both?

There are plenty of things to risk.

Look at each roll as a chance to ask, "what is the character putting on the line here?" That could be injury, magic, trust, or the attention of the forest.
-- "Additional Tips for Play", Trophy Dark p. 30

Only one of those things is directly risking your body or mind! Or maybe two, if when you put magic at stake you're staking your ability to ever use a ritual again, rather than risking that a ritual will run out and you'll need to roll with dark to set it in motion again.
If you lose the trust of another hunter, that might put your body and mind in danger in the future. If you get the attention of the forest, that might put your body and mind in danger in the future. But they're not at risk right now.
And that's assuming you're playing Trophy Dark, arguably the most abstract of the lot with the least defined other things to risk. If you've got something like Trophy Gold going, then you've also got an entire backpack full of tools and combat gear that you might be using and risk losing through damage or misadventure. Admittedly, you'd need to use your combat gear in an unusual way for your mind and body not to be at risk, but Trophy Gold's vibe absolutely supports that kind of outside-the-box thinking. And of course you're not simply risking attention from "the forest" as a monolith, since most incursions tend to compartmentalize their threats.

For sure!
Scenario: You're trying to sneak into a heavily guarded compound.
Risky Task: Disable the security cameras.
Hope: Successfully disable the cameras without being detected.
Possible things that could go wrong (without risking mind/body directly): Trigger an alarm, leave traces of tampering that are later discovered, accidentally short out the power to the entire compound (attracting attention), run out of time before disabling all the cameras.
Dark Die? Not necessarily. If you're simply disabling the cameras from a remote location, there's no immediate risk to your physical or mental well-being. However, if you're physically infiltrating the compound to disable the cameras, then you'd add a dark die, as capture or injury becomes a real possibility.
The "risking your mind or body" clause is there to add an extra layer of danger and consequence to tasks that involve direct physical or psychological peril. It doesn't mean that all risky tasks must involve such peril. The beauty of the system is its flexibility in handling a wide range of risky situations.

For now it's more like a general assumption about what risk might look like for something other than mind or body. But I'm not sure this is exactly how it works in Trophy. Could you please back it up with something like a citation of a game text, or personal experience of playing Trophy games?

Our group was trying to steal this ancient artifact from a flooded ruin – classic dungeon crawl stuff. My character, Elara, was the nimble rogue type, good at climbing and sneaking. We get to this chamber, and the artifact is on a pedestal in the middle of a pool of murky water. But the ceiling is covered in these weird, glowing fungi, and they're dripping this viscous goo into the water.
The GM describes it like, 'The air is thick with spores, and the goo sizzles when it hits the water, releasing a foul-smelling vapor.' Obviously, we're like, 'Okay, this is bad news.'

My plan was to swing across the chamber using my rope and grab the artifact. Risky action, for sure. I had a couple of Ruin dice already from earlier encounters (mostly from getting lost and nearly eaten by giant centipedes – good times).
I roll, and… ugh, mixed results. I succeed in getting across, but the GM says, 'As you swing, your rope brushes against one of the larger fungi. It bursts, showering you in the goo

Absolutely
Players voluntarily choose if they want to add a dark die in Trophy games.
Their characters are risking their minds or bodies because players add dark dice, not vice versa.
Jason Cordova, the publisher of the Trophy RPG (as well as the author of The Hester's Mill incursion), confirms this in the "How to Run Trophy Gold: Combat and Risk" podcast:

the next part of the procedure is adding a dark die

Most players in Trophy Gold tend to wait before adding a dark die:

90% of the time in Trophy Gold the players usually opt to wait for the dark die. They know they can add it in later, after they see the first result of their light dice, and that's perfectly fine

However, in Trophy Dark players choose dark dice more often:

in Trophy Dark, because the characters are gonna be finished at the end of a session, and because it's a sort of "play to lose" style of game, players lot more likely to want to take the dark dice

The thing is, Trophy is a game of collaborative storytelling. It assumes some part of the game goes out of character. Adding a dark die is an OoC action. A player starts with 1 die, then they might accept the Devil's Bargain, then they might add one dark dice, increasing their chance of success, but also taking the risk of increasing their Ruin. They can also reroll, adding more dark dice. The exception is using a Ritual — in this case a player has to add at least one dark die.
